# Keras multi-class semantic segmentation label

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

For semantic segmentations, you generally end up with the last layer being something like

`output = Conv2D(num_classes, (1, 1), activation='softmax')`

My question is, how do I prepare the labels for this?  For example, if I have 10 classes to identify, each with a different colour.  For each label image, do I need to apply masking for one particular colour, turn this into grayscale image so that I can compare with 1 filter from the model output?  Or is there a way to pass one full RGB picture in as the label?

Comment: Probably you want to one-hot-encode the segmented label images, such that every pixel in the output is associated with a binary vector such as `[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]` in the case of 10 classes.

Comment: @sdcbr sorry could you elaborate on the one hot encode label images? Is it with the same method I mentioned?

Comment: The output of your network will be an image with 10 channels, where each pixel will consist of a vector of probabilities that sum to one (due to the softmax). Example: `[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.05,0.05,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2]`. You want your labels images to be in the same shape: an image with 10 channels, and each pixel is a binary vector with a 1 at the index of the class and 0 elsewhere. Your segmentation loss function is then the pixel-wise crossentropy.

Comment: @sdcbr ok I get it, thank you.  just another question though, I thought softmax would be applied to each channel individually (so all pixels in one channel sums to 1), or is Keras smart enough to know I want the same pixel in all channels to sum to 1 instead?

Comment: That's actually a good question. Probably you will have to modify the output a bit. Perhaps look at [this](https://github.com/divamgupta/image-segmentation-keras/blob/master/Models/Unet.py) example

Comment: The softmax in keras has an axis parameter: https://keras.io/activations/#softmax

Comment: @sdcbr yeah I found the axis parameter as well, and after testing it out, it does seem to work. thanks for your help.

Comment: Nice to hear that! I'll add it as an answer for future reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of your network will be an image with 10 channels, where each pixel will consist of a vector of probabilities that sum to one (due to the softmax). Example: [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.05,0.05,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2]. You want your labels images to be in the same shape: an image with 10 channels, and each pixel is a binary vector with a 1 at the index of the class and 0 elsewhere. Your segmentation loss function is then the pixel-wise crossentropy.

For implementation: the softmax in keras has an axis parameter: https://keras.io/activations/#softmax

Answer (score 0):

```
np_utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes)
```

When labels are (row,col), the output shape will be: (row, col, num_classes)

example:
https://github.com/naomifridman/Unet_Brain_tumor_segmentation