# U-net Final Layer

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I'm trying to do an image segmentation problem where I want to segment 5 objects in an image. I'm using a U-net architecture. My final layer looks like this:

```
conv_final = Conv2D(OUTPUT_MASK_CHANNELS, (1, 1))(up_conv_224)
conv_final = Activation('sigmoid')(conv_final)

model = Model(inputs, conv_final, name="ZF_UNET_224")
```

However I get an error saying:

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_24 to have shape (224, 224, 5) but got array with shape (224, 224, 3)

This is the generator that I'm using

```
    image_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',  # this is the target directory
        target_size=(224, 224),
        color_mode = 'rgb',# all images will be resized to 150x150
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode=None,
        seed = 1)  # since we use binary_crossentropy loss, we need binary labels

# this is a similar generator, for validation data
    mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        color_mode = 'rgb',
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode=None,
        seed = 1)



    train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)
```

What can I do to fix this? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Your mask_generator is giving 3 channel image instead of 5 channel. Your model expects a 5 channel target.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but how do I get it to produce a 5 channel image?

Comment: You are probably providing an RGB image as mask. You need to convert your masks to have binary labels at each pixel. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51590843/keras-multi-class-semantic-segmentation-label?noredirect=1#comment90291532_51590843) which handles the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the data into one hot encoded format.

Use `from keras.utils import to_categorical`